# Using selenium, how can I only find first N elements to run faster?

Tags: python, selenium

The goal is trying to parse out a field faster from a large html file. The html is not well structured and has ten thousand "div tags" without a name/id to search for. I can only search the text with the pattern like "common stock", but the desired field may not be the first one.

I have used:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(MyLocalFileName)
browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
```

The find_elements took 5 minutes to parse this file. Please note that find_element, which gives the first element, may not contain the field I need. But find_elements will take so long and it is wasteful.

For example, I am trying to parse how many shares:
 
related line: "4601075000 shares of common stock" 
unrelated lines: "XXX Company increased shares of outstanding common stock"

Can I somehow find the first-element, if not desired, loop to the "next element"? Or can I only "find first N elements"?

Comment: you need to use a better locator.  What would define "if not desired"?

Comment: I revised the question to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to share the url if it's public?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider changing your [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) to XPath

XPath provides [position()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function which allows you to limit the result set to the given range so if you call [find_elements_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) method like:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/*[position()<=3]")
```

it will return only first 3 div objects instead of scanning the whole [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: Great and thanks for your reply. Actually, since "[] has a higher priority than //", the correct syntax is:                                 
    e_divs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div)[position()<=3]")